# How to make my gvimrc file use my vimrc file (VIM)

Tags: vim

TDLR; I am unable to edit gvim using the _vimrc file

Basically, I want to change some default settings (like background color) in the GUI version of vim (gvim). However, when I make changes to my .vimrc file, my gvim does not react to the changes.

I already have

if has("gui_number")
set number
colorscheme desert
endif

in my .vimrc file, and from what I've read that should make changes in my GVIM, but it doesn't.

I even tried to type some random stuff in the .vimrc file to see if GVIM would display an error, which it did not.

So i think the problem may be my gvim isn't reading my .vimrc file at all. So this may be a pathing problem?

This below is my .vimrc file

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
jhgfjhgjhg (This here was to test for an error)

if has('gui_running')
    set number
    colorscheme desert
endif


set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg1 = substitute(arg1, '!', '\!', 'g')
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = substitute(arg2, '!', '\!', 'g')
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = substitute(arg3, '!', '\!', 'g')
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      if empty(&shellxquote)
        let l:shxq_sav = ''
        set shellxquote&
      endif
      let cmd = '"' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  let cmd = substitute(cmd, '!', '\!', 'g')
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3
  if exists('l:shxq_sav')
    let &shellxquote=l:shxq_sav
  endif

endfunction






Here is my .GVIMRC file

version 6.0
if &cp | set nocp | endif
let s:cpo_save=&cpo
set cpo&vim
map! <S-Insert> *
vmap  "*d
map Q gq
vmap [% [%m'gv``
vmap ]% ]%m'gv``
vmap a% [%v]%
vmap gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
nmap gx <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
vnoremap <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis :call netrw#BrowseXVis()

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>NetrwBrowseX :call netrw#BrowseX(expand((exists("g:netrw_gx")? g:netrw_gx : '<cfile>')),netrw#CheckIfRemote())

vmap <C-Del> "*d
vmap <S-Del> "*d
vmap <C-Insert> "*y
vmap <S-Insert> "-d"*P
nmap <S-Insert> "*P
inoremap  u
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set backup
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
set display=truncate
set guioptions=egmrLT
set helplang=En
set history=200
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set langnoremap
set nolangremap
set nrformats=bin,hex
set ruler
set runtimepath=~/vimfiles,C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Vim/vimfiles,C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Vim\\vim81,C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\pack\\dist\\opt\\matchit,C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Vim/vimfiles/after,~/vimfiles/after
set scrolloff=5
set ttimeout
set ttimeoutlen=100
set undofile
set wildmenu
" vim: set ft=vim :
```

I would hope that my gvim would display lines and a different background, but nothing happens.

edit: should my _vimrc file look exactly like my gvimrc?

Comment: In `gvim`, if you run `:echo $MYVIMRC`, is the path display the same as your `.vimrc`?

Comment: Yes, it is C:/Program Files (x86)\VIM\_vimrc They should both be the same correct? Isn't .gvimrc supposed to use .vimrc first?

Comment: It does indeed. I used your files that you provided and it behaves as expected (I think, look, at the top is gvim, at the bottom left the trace of starting vim or gvim and at the bottom right is vim: https://imgur.com/a/1EQoURM)

Comment: However. I am running on Linux, not on Windows.

Comment: so maybe its a windows thing... I read somewhere that I have to manually create a .vimrc file, which I havent yet. Am I misunderstanding .vimrc with _vimrc?

Comment: Do you have a `_vimrc` and a `.vimrc`? Same question for `.gvimrc` and `_gvimrc`? From https://superuser.com/a/86269, the 4 would be used in a specific order.

Comment: I can only find a _vimrc under my Vim directory. I think I'm maybe supposed to make a .vimrc file in my home directory.

Comment: btw, it would not hurt to review `:help initialization`.

Comment: your `_vimrc` should be enough, same for `_gvimrc`.

Comment: Hey man I figured it out. So apparently I was supposed to create a _vimrc file in my home directory. I went to vim, typed in :e $HOME/_vimrc
And then put the new settings and saved, which then made my GVIM settings work like intended.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out guys.
So apparently I was supposed to create a _vimrc file in my home directory.

If you are on windows 7 and having the problem where you cant edit your _vimrc file in your VIM directory to change gvimrc, then its because you are trying to edit the wrong _vimrc!! You need to make a different user one in your home directory!

Windows 7:

Open vim, type in :e $HOME/_vimrc
And then put the new settings and save (then reopen GVIM)